# Set a global policy for floats positioning

Tags: floats, positioning

I have a document with many floats (figures, specifically).  I want to be able to change the global floats positioning policy from `htbp` to just `h` (or even `H` with the floats package).  For my-own reasons, I don't want to do this by appending the `[h]` argument to each float env.

One option that I can think of is using a macro:

```
\newcommand{\mypos}{h} % or htbp
\begin{figure}[\mypos]...
```

I also prefer not to do that - It is cumbersome.

Is there a way to set the global float positioning argument globally?

Comment: If you accept an answer, it would be nice to also upvote it. (This is also true for my answer to your question abour listings and subfigure. ;-))

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Some lines in the preamble should do the trick.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fps@figure}{!ht}
\renewcommand{\fps@table}{!ht}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 7):

You may use the [`floatrow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package and its `\floatplacement` macro:

```
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatplacement{figure}{!ht}
\floatplacement{table}{!ht}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatplacement{figure}{!ht}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
% \centering% default with "floatrow"
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]