# How to set default positioning of figure/table document wide

Tags: floats, positioning

I'm writing my thesis and I find myself adding `[hb]`s and `[ht]`s to all figures and tables.

Is there a way to make this global for the whole document?
Preferably with the option to override it for certain figure/table instances.

Comment: Just found my question is already asked and answered before: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6456/set-a-global-policy-for-floats-positioning?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set a global option for all figures and tables, use the following:

```
\makeatletter
  \providecommand*\setfloatlocations[2]{\@namedef{fps@#1}{#2}}
\makeatother
\setfloatlocations{figure}{htbp}
\setfloatlocations{table}{htbp}
```

(Just change `htbp` to whatever option you want.)

This is an idea of Lars Madsen (aka. [daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3929/daleif)); see [page 143 in his LaTeX book](http://data.imf.au.dk/system/latex/bog/version3/beta/ltxb-2011-09-13-20-10.pdf#page=169) (in Danish).

I haven't tried but I will guess that you can just set an option for the specific tables/figures which should have another option.

P.S. You have to put the code above in your preamble.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thnx! (will upvote when I reach 15 rep)