# Specifying the default behaviour of floats in Koma-Script

Tags: floats, koma-script

I want to specify the default behavior of floats to be `htbp` and I want to do this in a class definition for the whole document. I already found `floatpos` in the documentation, but this does not affect the default of existing documents does it?

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6456/18674 solve your problem?

Comment: Yes. Thanks! I searched stackexchange, but did not find this one.

Comment: Great, I will then vote to close it as a duplicate.